# Get result of search of website, without actually "opening" the site

Tags: search, web, show

I'd like to code a website where you can find search results from many websites. 
So my question is, if this scenario is possible and if yes, if you guys have any suggestions how I would be able to do this.

Here my workflow:

1. I search for something on my website. For example: "asdf"
2. My code then executes the search from the other website. for example:

   https://www.google.ch/#q=asdf&safe=images
3. Then there will be shown some results, of course. But how can I directly take the results and show them on my website, without opening the other website?

I have to say, that the websites I'm looking for, haven't got any API for that.

Answer (score 0):

I probably wouldn't recommend to scrap a web page directly in the client.

I'm not even sure if you can achieve it easily without getting some Cross Domain Policy problems anyway.

A solution like APIfy might help you doing what you want:

http://apify.heroku.com/resources

Or you can still make your own server site API "layer" for this particular website?
Keeping in mind that scrapping a web page is always a fragile process where the format can chance at any moment.